# send event object via `dispatch` in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, event-handling, vuex

If an `addEventListener` callback is passed, for example, via an arrow function, then everything works, but then I cannot remove the listener via `removeEventListener`.

```
export const actions = {
  open() {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('open')
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.dispatch('clickListener', e))
  },
  close() {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.remove('open')
    document.removeEventListener('click', (e) => this.dispatch('clickListener', e))
  },
  toggle() {
    if (document.querySelector('nav').classList.contains('open')) {
      this.dispatch('close')
    } else {
      this.dispatch('open')
    }
  },
  clickListener(ctx, e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're creating a new anonymous function in each call to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, so `removeEventListener` is not able to find the originally created callback.

Instead of the inline anonymous function, cache the created callback that is passed to `addEventListener` so that the cached result could be later passed to `removeEventListener`:

```js
let clickHandler = null

export const actions = {
  open() {
    // remove any existing callback (null ignored)
    document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)

    clickHandler = (e) => this.dispatch('clickListener', e)
    document.addEventListener(j'click', clickHandler)
  },
  close() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    clickHandler = null
  }
}
```